# Google Compute Engine, mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, google-compute-engine

Let me say first that any help will be greatly appreciated.

I've setup an instance on GCE. I'm using gcutil to access the instance. I've installed mySQL and mySQL Workbench. mySQL starts up fine, but would like to use mySQL Workbench. When I run mySQL Workbench, I get:

**Message: Gnome keyring daemon seems to not be available: Stored passwords will be lost once quit
GTX-WARNING: connot open display

I've tried setting my default display back to my localhost, with:
    export display=127.0.0.1

I even install gnome.

Any ideas how to get past this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear where your X Display server is running.  What you need to do is somehow get the X client (mySQL Workbench) talking to your X server (the display server running on your workstation/laptop).  A common way to do this is to tunnel that connection over SSH.

If I make the (big) assumption that you are running on a mac and launching using `gcutil` from there, you probably want to do something like this:

First, on your mac, download and start up [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).  If you are running Linux locally you can skip this.  If you are on Windows I don't have any recent experience or advice there.

Next, create and configure your virtual machine.  Make sure that `xauth` ends up being installed.  If it isn't, you won't be able to forward the X connection over SSH.  You'll see an error in the next step.

You may have to restart the shell on your host machine at this point.  You then want to SSH into your GCE instance with something like:

```
gcutil ssh --ssh-arg=-Y <my-instance>
```

Now things should be set up so that any X programs running in your instance forward over the SSH connection to the X server running on your workstation.  You can confirm this by running this in the VM:

```
me@instance $ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

---

An alternate approach is to download and run your mySQL client on your workstation/laptop and have it talk to the database directly.  You can do this also by tunneling the mySQL connection (TCP port 3306) over SSH also.  Run something like this:

```
gcutil ssh --ssh_arg="-L3306:localhost:3306" <my-instance>
```

You can now launch and run MySQL Workbench locally and connect to the remote database.  Just connect to localhost:3306 on your local machine and that connection will be forwarded to 3306 on the remote machine.

There is a lot of information out there on doing [SSH port forwarding](https://www.google.com/search?q=port+forwarding+ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Display should be set to your workstation IP address, not to GCE instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yuri, but doesn't 127.0.0.1 do that to localhost? Before submitting the question, I tried using the IP Addr given by my MAC at System Preferences, but that didn't work either. Any other suggestions?